# Compile Laravel blade component from string

Tags: laravel

I have a pagebuilder where i store {variable} in the database. When loaded on the frontend i want the variable to be translated to blade components.

```
$replacers = [
  'x-system-counters' => '<x-system-counters :data="$gloabal_variable"></x-system-counters>',
  'x-system-status' => '<x-system-status :data="$gloabal_variable"></x-system-status>',
];

$page = \App\Page::first();

$text = $page->content;
foreach ($replacers as $key => $value) {
    $text = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $text);
}
```

```
//Bladefile

{!! $text !!}
```

Any idea of how to solve this? I have tried the `Blade::compileString($text)` with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, this was actually very easy. Laravel always delivers

```
$replacers = [
  'x-system-status' => view('compontents.system-status', $data)->toHtml(),
];

$page = \App\Page::first();

$text = $page->content;
foreach ($replacers as $key => $value) {
    $text = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $text);
}
```

Comment: This works great but you have the pass the $data from the controller you are writing this into . So this will not pull the data from /app/view/components/.....

Answer (score 1):

## Basics

You can achieve this by following below steps:

1. Create a template which can be dynamic(from db or anywhere) and then replace fixed variables from that template with values. I suppose `$startpage->content` is the dynamic template you're trying to compile.
2. Replace variables with values using `$startpage->content`, then pass it to a simple blade with only one variable `{!! $text !!}`.

## Solution

You can give any content you like to `view` function, *view* complies it and you can convert it to html and pass to everywhere you want.

Something like below code may help you:

```
$page = \App\Page::first();

$template = $startpage->content;

$desired_text = '<x-system-counters :data="$gloabal_variable"></x-system-counters>';

$text = preg_replace('/{{\$x_system_counters}}/', $desired_text, $$template)

$html = view('for_compile_view', compact('text'))->toHtml();
```

**templates**

```
your contents plus {{$x_system_counters}}
```

**for_compile_view.blade.php**

```
{!! $text !!}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but that did't work at all. the blade components are not compiled. :(

Comment: Why? Please give more details of the errors and the results.

Comment: No errors, it's just not compiled. The element is listed in the html like this: <x-system-counters></x-system-counters>

I use my loop instead of your preg_replace, becuase i have several of different components to load.