# Render Laravel blade template as string without escaped chars and line breaks?

Tags: laravel, render, laravel-blade, mermaid

I've a pretty complicated blade layout, it's not strictly HTML as I'm using it to construct code for mermaid diagrams (https://mermaid-js.github.io/).

The code is generating fine, but when I render the blade template to a string it outputs with escaped characters and line breaks eg:

`$code = view('holiday.diagram')->render();`

**OUTPUT**:

```
graph TD\npeople[\"<strong>PEOPLE<\/strong>\n<hr \/> <strong>PERSON FIRST NAME<\/strong>: FOO BAR <br \/><strong>Number of TRAVELLERS<\/strong>: 6<br \/>
```

How can I remove these escaped chars and display the code as is? I've tried `htmlspecialchars-decode()` but it does not remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be html, use method `toHtml()`

```
view('holiday.diagram')->toHtml();
```

Comment: This removes the html attributes unfortunately.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234870/6212294) may help you